# integração PicPay: Problema

Tags: php, libcurl, php-7

Estou com problemas com o **Gateway** ***PicPay*** para fazer uma **integração**.

Estou seguindo o *manual* informado por eles no **link** abaixo:

https://ecommerce.picpay.com/doc/

Bom estou fazendo assim:

```
<?php

$urlLoja     = "http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br";

$urlPicPay   = "https://appws.picpay.com/ecommerce/public/payments";

/*
AQUI VÃO AS VARIÁVEIS $headers, $dados e $buyer mostradas mais abaixo
*/


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPicPay);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode ( $dados ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Na parte que diz no **código**  ***aqui vão as variáveis***, fiz 3 tentativas:

**Tentativa 1:**

```
$headers = array();
$headers["Content-Type"]   =  "application/json";
$headers["X-Picpay-Token"] =  "d12eac65-ddf3-4e6a-a7de-8a1d04c46a92";

$buyer = array();
$buyer["firstName"]        =  "Carlos";
$buyer["lastName"]         =  "Alberto";
$buyer["document"]         =  "12345678900";
$buyer["email"]            =  "carcleo@gmail.com";
$buyer["phone"]            =  "+55 32 3721-6149";

$dados = array();
$dados["referenceId"]      =  "1234";
$dados["callbackUrl"]      =  $urlLoja . "/picpay.php";
$dados["returnUrl"]        =  $urlLoja . "/picpayReturn.php";
$dados["value"]            =  "222.22";
$dados["buyer"]            =  $buyer;
```

**Tentativa 2:**

```
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type   : application/json';
    $headers[] = 'X-Picpay-Token : d12eac65-ddf3-4e6a-a7de-8a1d04c46a92';

    $buyer = array();
    $buyer[] = "firstName      :   Carlos";
    $buyer[] = "lastName       :   Alberto";
    $buyer[] = "document       :   12345678900";
    $buyer[] = "email          :   carcleo@gmail.com";
    $buyer[] = "phone          :   +55 32 3721-6149";

    $dados = array();
    $dados[] = "referenceId    :   " . 1234;
    $dados[] = "callbackUrl    :   " . $site . "/picpay.php";
    $dados[] = "returnUrl      :   " . $site . "/picpayReturn.php";
    $dados[] = "value          :   " . 222.22;
    $dados[] = "buyer          =>   " . $buyer;
```

**Tentativa 3**

```
$headers  = array ( 
      "Content-Type   => application/json",
      "x-picpay-token => d12eac65-ddf3-4e6a-a7de-8a1d04c46a92"
);

$dados = array ( 
           "referenceId"    =>   1234,
           "callbackUrl"    =>   $site . "/picpay.php",
           "returnUrl"      =>   $site . "/picpayReturn.php",
           "value"          =>   222.22,
           "buyer"          =>   array (
                "firstName" =>   "Carlos",
                "lastName"  =>   "Alberto",
                "document"  =>   12345678900,
                "email"     =>   "carcleo@gmail.com",
                "phone"     =>   "+55 32 3721-6149" //  +55 27 12345-6789
           ),
);
```

Todas 3 dão o mesmo retorno para:

```
print_r (result);
```

**{"message":"Erro: token x-picpay-token obrigatório.","code":"401"}**

Pela *mensagem* de **erro**, diz que o problema é no **token** que está inválido. No entanto, é do *painel* da **PicPay** que estou tirando este **token**.

Eles dizem que é erro de código. Mas não vejo erro.

Se tiver erro ai, por favor, me mostrem.

**Obs.:**

Conforme orientação do pessoal da **PicPay**, eu devo seguir esse *padrão* que está na **linguagem** *própria* da **Curl** e passar para **PHP**.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://appws.picpay.com/ecommerce/public/payments \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-picpay-token: 5b008cef7f321d00ef2367b2' \
  -d '{
    "referenceId": "102030",
    "callbackUrl": "http://www.sualoja.com.br/callback",
    "returnUrl": "http://www.sualoja.com.br/cliente/pedido/102030",
    "value": 20.51,
    "buyer": {
      "firstName": "João",
      "lastName": "Da Silva",
      "document": "123.456.789-10",
      "email": "test@picpay.com",
      "phone": "+55 27 12345-6789"
    }
}'
```

Será que eu passei para PHP 3 vezes errado?

Obrigado!

Comment: O erro 401, credenciais de autenticação não válidas para o recurso de destino, já dá uma boa dica. Eu não li a documentação, mas você tem certeza que a chave é essa? Não existe chave de ambiente de teste e outra de produção? Outra dúvida, na sua chave, não seria o caso de remover os hífens? (d12eac65ddf34e6aa7de8a1d04c46a92). Passe (x-picpay-token:) parâmetro em minúscula.

Comment: então, vou fazer esse teste. Mas não, o token  é esse mesmo. copiado do próprio PicPay

Comment: Algum progresso?

Comment: Sim, adicionei como resposta/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:

O único inconveniente aqui é que a PicPay na tela de pagamentos pede para scanear uma Code .

E isso pode não ser tão fácil em Desktops. O que vai dificultar e muito a vida da gente!

Muito provavelmente vamos sair da PicPay por esse motivo.

Mas, segue o código que deu certo:

```
<?php

$urlSite     = "http://www.urlsite.com.br";

$urlPicPay = "https://appws.picpay.com/ecommerce/public/payments";

$XPicpayToken = "X-Picpay-Token: SEU TOKEN";

$headers  = array ( 
      "Content-Type:application/json",
      $XPicpayToken
);

$buyer = array (
                "firstName" =>   "Nome",
                "lastName"  =>   "Sobrenome",
                "document"  =>   "12345678900",
                "email"     =>   "gmail@gmail.com",
                "phone"     =>   "+55 33 3333 3333" //  +55 27 12345-6789
           );

$dados = array ( 
           "referenceId"    =>   1245,
           "callbackUrl"    =>   $urlSite . "/picpay.php",
           "returnUrl"      =>   $urlSite . "/picpayReturn.php",
           "value"          =>   222.22,
           "buyer"          =>   $buyer
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPicPay);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode ( $dados ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$erro  = curl_error($ch);

$resultPHP = json_decode($result, true);


if ( isset ( $resultPHP["paymentUrl"] ) ){

    header ("Location: " . $resultPHP["paymentUrl"]);

} else {

    print_r( $erro );

}

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Comment: ok. Então mesmo no exemplo deles o token não conter hífen`'x-picpay-token: 5b008cef7f321d00ef2367b2'`, não quer dizer nada. Onde estava o problema exatamente, conseguiu descobrir?

Comment: na geração dos meus arrays.

Comment: Entendido, agora! boa.

Comment: valeu. Obrigado